# Laravel- datatables inline editing and use autocomplete for multitables

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, autocomplete

I have a complicated problem, I have a table that contains data as Im using datatable, table **Checks** have relationship with other table **Vendors**
what I want just when click on cell **vendor_id** make it editable and use autocomplete function to fill or edit current data.
I want table to be editable like this example
https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple

[my table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDnWB.jpg)

**Check table:**

details
description

vendor_id

**Vendors table**:

vendor_id

vendor_name

now the name of vendor appears in the datatable but dont know why its inside brackets and "" **[{"vendor_name":"Raul"}]**
so All I want just to show vendor_name and edit it using autocomplete and to store it in the Check Table by storing vendor_id not vendor name

Ajax

```
          var oTable = $('#users-table').DataTable({
            dom: 'flBrtip',   
            stateSave: true,
            paging:     true,
            pagingType: 'simple_numbers',
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                 url: 'custom-filter-data',
                    data: function(d) {
                          d.start_date = $('input[name=start_date]').val();
                           d.end_date = $('input[name=end_date]').val();
                         }
                         },
         columns : [
       {data: 'details', name: 'details'},
          {data: 'description', name: 'description'},
           {data: 'vendor_id',name:'vendor_id'},
          {data: 'category_id',name: 'category_id'},
        ],
         pageLength: 10,

        });
    oTable.draw();
```

Controller

```
   public function getCustomFilterData()
   {
  $arrStart = explode("/", Input::get('start_date'));
      $arrEnd = explode("/", Input::get('end_date'));
      $start = Carbon::create($arrStart[2], $arrStart[0], $arrStart[1], 0, 0, 0);
      $end = Carbon::create($arrEnd[2], $arrEnd[0], $arrEnd[1], 23, 59, 59);

    $orders = Checks::between($start, $end);
  return Datatables::of($orders)->editColumn('vendor_id', function ($user) 
    {
       $vendor =Vendors::select('vendor_name')->where('vendor_id',$user->vendor_id)->get();
     return ( $vendor);
   }) ->make( TRUE );
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `whereBetween()` instead `between()`?

Comment: no the date is working fine with no issues soe between is working but Im asking about how to make datatable editable and cells have autocomplete function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `->get();` which returns and array and thus the `[]`
If you only want one column (vendor_name) write it like this.

```
$vendor =Vendors::where('vendor_id',$user->vendor_id)->first();
return $vendor ? $vendor->vendor_name : '';
```

Explanation of get and first differences: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#retrieving-results

Comment: $vendor =Vendors::where('vendor_id',$user->vendor_id)->first();
return ( @$vendor->vendor_name);

Comment: That is indeed a better way to type it

Comment: What issue are you talking about?

Comment: how to make the cell of vendor editable and autocomplete

Comment: That I guess you need to check https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple . THe autocomplete can be a little more tricky since you'll probably have to use a 3rd party plugin like select2

Comment: I know this example but its very complex for me, Im still begginer

Comment: If doing so is complex, approach it by an easier way, open a popup to edit for example and a select2 search in the popup